# Closed path on a dodecahedron

Tags: mathematics, geometry, combinatorics, tiling

Your task is to draw lines between edges on a regular pentagon such that if you tile a dodecahedron with 12 identical copies of that pentagon you get a single closed line which does not intersect itself and which visits each face of the dodecahedron exactly twice. How many essentially different solutions exist?

Comment: Is it allowed to run a line along the edge of a pentagon such that it may go between two pentagons that are non-adjacent, and is not considered to 'visit' either of the other two pentagons that the edge divides?

Comment: Can copies of the pentagonal tile be reflected?

Comment: @Weather Vane: I do not exactly understand what you mean with a line that goes between two pentagons that are not adjacent. With visiting the face of the dodecahedron I mean that the line must cross some edge of that face such that the line has points with the inner of this face in common.

Comment: @AxiomaticSystem: No, the pentagons must be really identical.

Comment: If the line crosses the edge *at a vertex* then it need not cross the edge of the adjoining pentagon, but could follow another edge, to another polygon that the first one does not share an edge with, entering again at a vertex.

Comment: I only had in mind that a line starts and ends at well defined edges and not at a vertex. But if there are solution in the vertex case this would be nice too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2nd Update: I have found a small number of solutions.

> I found **6 distinct solutions** with a continuous path.
>
>  For a line to visit each face twice, there must be 2 entry and 2 exit points.
>  There are 10 distinct ways to arrange them around a pentagon.
>  These exclude reflections and rotations.
>  Moreover, there are two ways for the points to connect without crossing.
>  Here are the ten face arangements, with the joining variation in vertical pairs.
>
>  [image]
>
>  Only 4 of those 10 sets will make a dodecahedron with matching edges.
>  And only one (top right) will make a continuous path.
>  (It's clear on inspection that those with a closed edge loop will not.)
>
>  There were 210 possible arrangements.
>  Only 6 after removing rotational and reflection symmetry.
>  There are 3 versions of each of the path methods.
>
>  [image]

> [image]

Comment: The solutions are very "samey" within the distinct basic types described. With that many images I can't yet figure out how to compare them – it's impractical to do it empirically. Algorithmically I would have to align every face of the candidate with every face of every polyhedron in the 'solutions' list and check if they are in same orientation (and the mirror equivalents).

Comment: @  Weather Vane: Nice result so far! For the tiling with the pentagon with only small curves the number of essentially different tilings  can be easily derived manually with the result from https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121943/tiling-a-dodecahedron. For the mixed case this should work too.

Comment: Thanks, I am unconvinced that there are no 'continuous path' solutions for the other basic types. After finding that only some of the basic types could be built into a dodecahedron, at first I could not find any solutions with a continuous path, and it's possible that solutions for other types are hiding behind 'deficient code'.

Comment: @Herbert I've done rotational symmetry but I can't get my head around mirror symmetry yet.

Comment: @ Weather Vane First I agree that the only possible types are the two top right cases. Concerning the essential different types I really recommend to look just at the 5 ways the double tiles can be placed in each of both cases and to check if these make up a single closed loop.

Comment: @Herbert in the meantime my update was incorrect, I've rolled it back.

Comment: @Waether Vane From the 11 diagrams it is indeed difficult or even impossible  to see directly which diagrams are equivalent. But you count way to many if you also consider mirror images. In the mixed case where you found 6 solutions there must be even at least one pair which is related by rotation. I will try to figure it out.

Comment: The 5 of the first connection type are clearly different by inspection (the left half is the same in each, and the right half has 5 rotations). I looked algorithmically for mirror images but didn't find any.

Comment: One mistake I could identify easily. The fourth diagram does not give single closed loop. The three small curves  on top build an own loop.

Comment: As you mentioned, it isn't easy to trace the path, and I've just printed off the 4th one and followed it. I'm working on a version that connects the path off-face, so make it easier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148540/discussion-between-herbert-kociemba-and-weather-vane).

Comment: @HerbertKociemba I've finally solved the reflection symmetry :)

Comment: Finally! This is the result I  expected. Wasn’t it a nice little problem?

Comment: It kept me busy for a while, and I advanced my own graphics library a bit.